# Expected value with coin toss

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Person A throws a coin until head comes. Then he gets from Person B 1 million dollars. Person A pays  1 Dollar for the first round, double for the next, etc. Can Person A expect a win?

Does someone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: What is Number?  Does Mio mean million?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: @user650708 not really, "A win" is completely undefined in this context so there's no way to solve it.

Comment: This question is a variation on the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox), which has been discussed here [many times](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Petersburg+paradox).

Comment: @FredH thanks, this was exactly what I was searching for!